# Create dynamically Divs inside other Divs javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just want to ask a simple question. I'm having this code

```
<div id="mainContainer">
  <h2>Something</h2>
  <div id="leftColumn">
    <p><b>Left</b></p>
    <div id="dropContent">
      <div class="dragableBox hoehe1" id="box1">Box1 - 30</div>
      <div class="dragableBox hoehe2" id="box2">Box2 - 20</div>
      <div class="dragableBox hoehe3" id="box3">Box3 - 10</div>
      <div class="dragableBox hoehe4" id="box4">Box4 - 40</div>
      <div class="dragableBox hoehe5" id="box5">Box5 - 20</div> 
      <div class="dragableBox hoehe6" id="box6">Box6 - 10</div>
      <div class="dragableBox hoehe7" id="box7">Box7 - 20</div>
      <div class="dragableBox hoehe4" id="box8">Box8 - 10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightColumn">
    <div id="dropBox" class="dropBox">
      <p><b>Right</b></p>
      <div id="dropContent2"></div>     
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Which creates all the divs that I need. I want to be able to create the little inside boxes (box1, box2 etc.) dynamically with a javascript/jquery function. I need them to be inside the "left", which is inside the "something". The specifics for the boxes can be found in the classes dragableBox und hoehe*. In simple words, I need a javascriptfunction to create exatcly the same, that the HTML tags are doing in the moment.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _I need a javafunction to create exatcly the same_....`java !== javascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $div = $('<div class="dragableBox hoehe1" id="box1">Box1 - 30</div>');
$('#dropContent').append($div);

var $div = $('<div class="dragableBox hoehe2" id="box2">Box2 - 20</div>');
$('#dropContent').append($div);

//ETC....
```

Somethink like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this -  (*as you are using ID on box, you can directly access it with `#`. you dont need to worry if it is inside left or right as far as you **keep your IDs unique**.*)

```
var $div = $('<div>').text("something");
$('#box1').append($div);
$('#box2').append($div);
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert at the end of the container

```
var MyValue = "Box2 - 20";
$('<div class="dragableBox hoehe1" id="box1">' + MyValue +'</div>').appendTo($('#dropContent'));
```

Insert at the begining of the container

```
var MyValue = "Box2 - 20";
$('<div class="dragableBox hoehe1" id="box1">' + MyValue +'</div>').prependTo($('#dropContent'));
```